# Value for '*' attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin in row(s):

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, import-products

Not sure what is causing this problem.

The previous line which has the same value is valid. But this line is invalid.

[image: downloaded error file]

[image]

Comment: Is there any space before and after 1?

Comment: No, the whole column has the same value.